# pattern or model, an examplar: how to let the end-user customize your app to fit his needs?

Tags: .net

I'm trying to figure out from some time now how to develop a functionality to let the end user create some additional fields in the system without affecting the db schema? I tried searching on google but i don't even know how ask the right question:) is it even possible? any hints will be appreciated.

regards, Rafal

Comment: Apparently you're not sure which question to ask on here, either. Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: Could you ask a more specific question, ideally with a detailed example?

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you serialize the data into XML and store that? This way you don’t need to change the database at all. You could store the extra fields as a XML or VARCHAR(MAX) in the database.